# constructing an ISAM tree

Tags: algorithm, database-design, indexing, isam

i am having a bunch of nodes holding some data . this can be considered as leaf nodes.
I want to build an ISAM tree over these nodes. Is there a standard way of creating the non leaf nodes of an ISAM tree /B plus tree  / any tree for that matter. How to implement the tree structure.

Constraints: The height of the tree cannot be assumed. all the non leaf nodes should be full except the rightmost one.

I am planning on using a list structure to hold the key-value and node-index.

Thanks

Comment: Please comment if any more information is needed about the existing design / data

Comment: This answer shows one way of doing that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401009/sequentially-constructing-full-b-trees?rq=1

Comment: what would be the height of this tree?  and also if i implement this using a while loop what is the condition i have to use? I am thinking i will use log_2 (number of leaf nodes / data records per node) Really confused !!!!

Comment: My theory on that is a bit rusty - isn't it going to be something like logn(X) where n is the number of keys per node and X is the number of total keys in the tree?

Comment: we both have said the same thing mathematically... one more thing.. do u mean to say X is number of leaf nodes in the tree

Comment: i am trying to use list of lists in java to store each level of this tree  . any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Can any one tell me the relation ship between the index node  and the leaf page .  in case of binary tree it is 2n , 2n+1 . will it be  (no of child)*n ?

Comment: This is called a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree).